# AJAX in Rails. Cannot Create comment on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am trying to allow the user to create comments on a specific post, using AJAX in Rails. I get the form to show, but on create it does not work. In my form it says the href="/posts/post_id/comments/new" method="post". I think it should just be post/post_id/comments with a method="post", But I cannot get this to work.

The console just says no route matches POST post/id/comments/new because it is wrong obviously.

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

respond_to :html, :js

def index 
    @comments = Comment.all
end 

def new
    @new_comment = Comment.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
end
```

_form.html.erb in comments views

```
<%= simple_form_for post_comments_path, remote: true, html:{class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success", value: "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb (main view with posts)

```
    <div class="pull-left">
      <%= link_to new_post_comment_path(post), remote: true, method: :get do %>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">+Comment</button>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div id="comment-form" style="display:none;"></div>
    <% if post.comments.count > 0 %>
      <div id="comments"><%= render @comments %></div>
    <% end %>
```

new.js.erb in comments

```
$('#comment-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#comment-form').slideDown(350);
```

create.js.erb in comments

```
$('#comments').html("<%= j (render @comments) %>");
$('#comment-form').slideUp(350);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't pass path helper to form_for helper. Give it a model instead, it will generate correct url on it's own. Try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @new_comment, remote: true, html:{class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success", value: "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems that you are using nested resources. In that case, you will need to tweak your #new controller method.

```
def new
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @new_comment = Comment.new
end
```

And then pass both @post and @new_comment to form_for. Again, this should be enough for Rails to figure out where to post your form.

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @new_comment], remote: true, html:{class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success", value: "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE:**
You have a typo in create.js.erb, @comments isn't defined, it should be singular: @comment
Also make sure that you actually have _comment partial :)

```
$('#comments').html("<%= j (render @comment) %>");
$('#comment-form').slideUp(350);
```

Comment: the route is now correct for the post route. Thank You, but Im getting a 500 Error. I think it's the render @comments in the js file.

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):
    1: $('#comments').html("<%= j (render @comments) %>");
    2: $('#comment-form').slideUp(350);
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb__567074225368858152_70133586532740'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to tie the comment to the post via the form, you need to pass the `@post` into the path. So it would look like:

**UPDATED** after reading the comments below:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @new_comment], remote: true, html:{class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-success", value: "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the `@post`? That is why the path was rendering incorrectly.